# Remove particular characters in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I’ve got a script that pulls an image from a repo, manipulates it, and stores some info.

I’m trying to figure out how to strip the tags that append these variables. A variable might be `Nginx:23457@SHA256=xyz`

How can I make it so that I strip the `:23457` - the colon and any numbers preceding the colon, but not the `@` characters?

Comment: `bash` has extended parameter expansion by `${variable/pattern/replacement}`. You can use that, like `${tag/:*@/@}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to strip your pattrn
Let's say

```
x=Nginx:23457@SHA256=xyz
echo $x | awk -F'[:@]' '{ print $2 }'
```

will result in `23457`.

Here we specify `:` and `@` as field saperator using `-F` parameter and taking the output of second column after saperation.